# Is making a video calling and live broadcast app possible in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, live-streaming, videocall

I am new to Swift and I want to integrate video calling in my app using Swift. I want to make a live broadcasting video app where one host will come live and other clients can join him/her.

I tried several third party apps like **agora.io** but it didn't work for me. Do you guys have a better suggestions?

Comment: This can be closed as "seeking recommendations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try quickblox. It is a very smart solution, it can manage everything for you, your only task is to present the UI and the buttons. It is relatively cheap, even free for low user count. We have used it to create an "intercom" like application

[Quickblox website](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios)

Comment: But does it provides a one to many video call like live Broadcast? For example many students are streaming their teacher ?

Comment: Up to 12 participant https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/ios-video-conference